# Azure Web App - Python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 0] No error

Tags: python, django, azure, manage.py

I am trying to deploy my Django application with Azure DevOps as a Azure Web App. The application is pipelined and build to the web app but it will not run.
When I am trying to run `py manage.py runserver` in the Diagnostic Console i get the error below:

```
D:\Python34\python.exe: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 0] No error
```

Does anyone have a clue on what the issue might be?
This is the first project I am trying to deploy with Azure so my knownledge is not very good.
The project files are stored on the following location on the server

```
D:\home\site\wwwroot\<applicationName>
```

I am sometimes getting this error as well:

```
Window title cannot be longer than 1023 characters.
```

Filestructure

wwwroot 
--- applicationname 
------ api
------ applicationname 
------ .env
------ db.sqlite3 (empty and not in use)
------ manage.py
------ requirements.txt

**Things that have been tried to solved the issue**

1. Changing the filepath in Configuration -> Path Mappings -> Physical Path after an idea from Jason Pan
2. Add a web.config file (Added in wwwroot -> applicationname -> web.config). The Config file is pasted below. This resulted in the following error: `The specified CGI application encountered an error and the server terminated the process.`

Web.Config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>

  <handlers>
    <add name="httpPlatformHandler" path="*" verb="*"
               modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
  </handlers>

  <httpPlatform processPath="D:\home\python364x64\python.exe" arguments="manage.py runserver %HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT%" requestTimeout="00:04:00" startupTimeLimit="120" startupRetryCount="3" stdoutLogEnabled="true">
    <environmentVariables>
     <environmentVariable name="PYTHONPATH" value="D:\home\site\wwwroot"/>
    </environmentVariables>
  </httpPlatform>

 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Thank you for your help.

**SOLUTION** 
After huge help from Jason Pan i manage to set it up as a Container Service instead and the app is now working as it should! Thank you very much Jason!

Comment: Pls show me the content under `wwwroot` folder.

Comment: Due to the formatting I am adding this in the original post.

Comment: Try to create web app with windows container ^-^.

Comment: Due to azure web app is sandbox env, so we can't change any more, we need to use container web app. https://imgur.com/a/hFbK04e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Newest

Previous we change path, we need to modify it back.

[image]

Step 1. Add Extensions.

[image]

Step 2. Add web.config.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="PythonHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
    </handlers>
    <httpPlatform processPath="D:\home\python364x64\python.exe"
                  arguments="D:\home\site\wwwroot\manage.py runserver %HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT%"
                  stdoutLogEnabled="true"
                  stdoutLogFile="D:\home\LogFiles\python.log"
                  startupTimeLimit="60"
                  processesPerApplication="16">
      <environmentVariables>
        <environmentVariable name="PORT" value="%HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT%" />
      </environmentVariables>
    </httpPlatform>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Step 3. Make sure that the directory structure in your wwwroot folder is the same as mine.

[image]

Step 4. Run command `pip install python-decouple` in `python364x64`.

[image]

Step 5. Then your app will be ok. If also have issues, you can troubleshoot like me.

[image]

Test Result.

In local.

[image]

After deployed.

[image]

[image]

---

Your directory structure should look like this. And it will work fine.

wwwroot 
--- api
--- applicationname 
--- .env
--- db.sqlite3 (empty and not in use)
--- manage.py
--- requirements.txt

## In order to verify my guess, you can test like this in the portal.

[image]

Then restart your web app, if it works, it also can be a solution. The reason for this problem before was that the folder applicationname was added.

Comment: Hi and thank you for your response! 
I followed your steps changing the file path, but the error is still the same. I have noticed that I am getting a new error aswell when trying to run the manage.py runserver command ---> Window title cannot be longer than 1023 characters. Edit: Updated the original post with this error.

Comment: @MariusBekk Try to add webconfig file which contains httpplatformhandler.

Comment: I will try that, but am a little unsure on how so I will have to figure that out first. 
A another thing I found out is that when I try to edit the manage.py file from the diagnostic tool I can an error saying that I have no persmissions to do that... Can that be the issue or is it normal that you cannot write to the file from this view?

Comment: I added a Web.Config file, see the content in the original post. 
I am now getting this error: "The specified CGI application encountered an error and the server terminated the process"

Comment: @MariusBekk If possible you can upload your sample code without sensitive info,I can help you tomorrow.

Comment: @MariusBekk Because I don't have specific parameters, I can only make the local results consistent with the deployed results. Please remember to delete your source code sharing.

Comment: The data is not that secret as it is a dev environment with mostly dummydata.. You could get the .env file with the secrets as well if that helps? :)

Comment: @MariusBekk I'm not sure, but currently the local and azure running results are consistent.

Comment: I will try to replicate what you did first and let you know. Thank you so far for this amazing help :D

Comment: @MariusBekk If you need further help, pls let me know.

Comment: Python logfile: D:\home\python364x64\python.exe: can't open file 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\manage.py': [Errno 0] No error

Comment: The files are in the same place as you have them (Directly under wwwroot) - And I followed your steps to the letter.

Comment: @MariusBekk Can you check application logs on portal?

Comment: @MariusBekk Make sure your web.config under wwwroot folder, and same as mine.

Comment: The application log says the same thing (D:\home\python364x64\python.exe: can't open file 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\manage.py': [Errno 0] No error)

Comment: The web.config file is under wwwroot folder and the same as yours!

Comment: Can it be that for some reason it doesn't have the rights to run it? And do you know how to check this?

Comment: @MariusBekk Can you create a new sample for me with .env (no sensitive info) which I can run in my local. And when I success, I can give you more details.

Comment: Just let me know when you have the repo url and I will delete again :) Thank you!

Comment: @MariusBekk Pls delete your .env file and repo, I can run in my local. https://imgur.com/a/BbC4gHb

Comment: Done. A little side-note: I tried to create a new Azure Web app yesterday and push the code to that. Same error there.

Comment: @MariusBekk Your issue has been solved by yourself ?

Comment: @MariusBekk I am testing.