# HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure after Deployed the .Net core to Azure appservice

Tags: azure, azure-devops, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1, azure-appservice

I have recently upgraded my .Netcore webapi from 2.2 to 3.1 and deployed to azure app services.
Since then I got the below issue. I have reverted the release but still getting the same error.
I found few solutions for IIS but nothing for Azure app services .How to fix this?
[image]

Comment: Did you check event viewer ?

Comment: Event viewer is not available in Azure app services.

Answer (score 0):

## **[NEWEST]**

**Solution:**

*Reduce the version of `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions` to `3.1.17` or `3.1.16`.*

**Troubleshooting:**

1. Try to find `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions` on `scm` site.
2. I guess it don't include `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions` package when deploy, so try to use below code in `.csproj` file. But it failed.

   [image]
3. I try to find the reason on `scm` site, and I find it. On azure, `.net core 3.1` just support the version of `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions` are `3.1.17` and `3.1.16`.

   [image]

## **[PREVIOUS] The way to find the error logs**

Judging from the error message, your webapp did not start. To solve the problem, we can only locate the error by querying the log.

**You have the following two solutions to solve the problem. View the log:**

*Prerequisite: If you have successfully deployed the project before, please log in to the scm site to clean up all the files in the original `wwwroot` folder.*

## Plan 1:

Find the `web.config` file in the `wwwroot` folder and set `stdoutLogEnabled="true"`.

**You can refer to the following posts and github issues.**

1. [Azure Web App - Python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 0] No error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66936274/azure-web-app-python-cant-open-file-manage-py-errno-0-no-error/66949498#66949498)
2. [How to enable stdoutLogEnabled=true when site is deployed with Run From Package](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/31380)

After add the settings in `web.config`, we can check the logs.

## Plan 2:

Follow below picture, check `Application Event Logs`.

[image]

You also can refer my answer to `Collect .NET Profiler Trace` ([Azure - Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63053677/azure-unhandled-exception-system-io-filenotfoundexception)).

---

**After find the error, you can solve it quickly. If you also have some problem, you can create a new project without any sensitive info for us to reproduce your issues.**

Comment: Thanks for the help ! I have enabled stdoutLogEnabled="true" in web.config .It stdoutLog it shows the following error .  Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutralThe located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.                                         
         IF I deploy directly from local visual studio to app services it's good and service is up .but If I deploy through yaml(CI/CD) there the issue . Can you please suggest on this?

Comment: @mohan I find the reason, I will update the answer, if it helps you, you can accept it as answer, thanks.

Comment: Thanks much for your help and support !unfortunately this didn't work though I upgraded to 3.1.17 .Here is the error Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions, Version=3.1.17.0, The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions, Version=3.1.17.0      ,but dll is available in the www root folder

Comment: @mohan okey，please follow the code I provided in csproj, and also upgrade 3.1.17, and try again.

Comment: @mohan if also failed, pls try to copy and paste the dll from the folder, you can find the path in scm site. If it works, pls use ItemGroup tag.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67181866/azure-functions-dont-publish-appsettings-prod-json-file/67206074#67206074 . Try to modify csproj file, include.dll file when build and deploy.

Comment: Thanks for all your help @Jason Pan ! much appreciated. I have ended up by creating the new app service. It's working fine.